# Insert peity bar graph inside a datatable cell

Tags: javascript, charts, datatables

Good night friends.
I'm going crazy trying to insert a peity chart into a datatable cell, for some reason I can do it. Below I show the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                "ajax": {
                "url": "http://llx/query?db=telegraf&q=SELECT 
LAST(cpu_used) AS cpu, LAST(mem_used) AS mem, LAST(load) AS load, 
LAST(disk_await) AS disk_await FROM custom  where time >= '2019-01- 
01' GROUP BY hostname ORDER BY time",
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": "json",
                "cache": false,
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "dataSrc": "results.0.series[]"
                },
        deferRender: true,
        columns: [
            { data: 'tags.hostname' },
            { data: 'values.0.0',
            {data: 'values.0.1'},
            {data: 'values.0.2'},
            {data: 'values.0.3'},
            {data: 'values.0.4'},
            {'render': function(data, type, row meta) {
var sequence = "<span 
class='bar'>2,5,3,6,2,1</span>"
                       return sequence
                    }
                }
        ],
        rowId: 'extn',
        select: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Actualizar tabla',
                action: function () {
                    table.ajax.reload();
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );

$(function() {
    $('span.bar').peity('bar')
})
```

For some reason it only shows me the data but not the graph.

I used this example to guide me:

http://jsfiddle.net/Iarwain/zvhvpLum/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=zvhvpLum

Answer (score 0):

you missed an important part of datatables.... - the 'render'

```
{var sequence = "<span class='bar'>2,5,3,6,2,1</span>"
                   return sequence
                }
            }
```

should be

```
"render": function(data, type, row, meta){
  {var sequence = "<span class='bar'>2,5,3,6,2,1</span>"
                   return sequence
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I have the render, but when I wanted to cut the code delete it without intention, I will update. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work either. It must be simple but I can not do it. Basically I need to recover the value of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a drawCallback function to invoke your piety chart. So every time the table redraws it creates the chart. More information here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback

**EDIT**

After following the link to the example and trying to create a bar there was an issue with trailing commas in the string within the span. I've updated the JSFiddle in the example to get it working... the only thing I can think of is that the string that is being returned in the render function is not quite right:

```
"render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
    var arr = []
    for (var i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
        arr.push(parseInt(row[i], 10));
    }
    return `<span class="bar">${arr.join(",")}</span>`
}
```

I guess the thing to do is also to check you're including the piety library within your page as well. If you check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/9dam5ef1/) you'll see the bar working.

Are there any messages within the console and what does the markup within your cell look like?

Comment: Hello, in the example it does not use it and it works well.